# Suggestion needed with Conditional mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables

I have 2 mySQL tables as following.

```
CREATE TABLE occupation_competence(grpid varchar(15), skillid varchar(15));
INSERT INTO occupation_competence(grpid,skillid) VALUES("II-Ob","IL-X");
INSERT INTO occupation_competence(grpid,skillid) VALUES("II-Ob","II-1");
INSERT INTO occupation_competence(grpid,skillid) VALUES("II-Ob","IS-1");
INSERT INTO occupation_competence(grpid,skillid) VALUES("II-Oc","IL-X");
INSERT INTO occupation_competence(grpid,skillid) VALUES("II-Oc","II-1");
INSERT INTO occupation_competence(grpid,skillid) VALUES("AA-RS","IL-X");
INSERT INTO occupation_competence(grpid,skillid) VALUES("AA-RS","AA-1");


CREATE TABLE personnel_competences(id varchar(12), skillid varchar(50));
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(79,"IT-1");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(79,"II-1");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(79,"IL-X");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(56,"AA-X");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(80,"AA-X");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(80,"IL-X");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(80,"AA-1");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(8,"II-1");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(8,"IL-X");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(21,"YO-X");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(51,"AA-1");
INSERT INTO personnel_competences(id, skillid) VALUES(51,"IL-X ");
```

And I need to extract data/id from the table this way:

```
| AA-RS | 80 |
| AA-RS | 51 |
| II-Oc | 79 |
| II-Oc | 8  |
```

Here, For example,  in the first (occupation_competence) table, under the same grpid ("AA-RS") we have 2 different values "IL-X" and "AA-1". Then we come to the second (personnel_competences) table and we find the id that must have these 2 values at least. In this case, id no 80 and 51 has the same values at least, so we take it.

Another example, in the first table, "II-Ob" has 3 values: "IL-X", "II-1", "IS-1". Then we go the second table and try to find out the ids which must have these 3 values at least. As there are no id that has all these 3 values, so we dont take it.

In the same way, "II-Oc" has 2 values: "IL-X" and "II-1". And in the second table, id no 79 and 8 has these 2 values at least, so we take it.

What SQL/mySQL query/condition should I use in this case? Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no duplicates in either table, you can use `join` and `group by`:

```
select oc.grpid, pc.id
from occupation_competence oc join
     personnel_competences pc
     on oc.skillid = pc.skillid
group by oc.grpid, pc.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from occupation_competence oc2 where oc2.grpid = oc.grpid);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f4f056a1162e586cca0a8fb7928b7a4) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This assumes that the space in the skill in the last row of `personnel_competences` is a typo.  If not, you'll need to remove spaces as part of the query.